# Why does my C# WPF program keep executing lines after Application.Shutdown()?

Tags: c#, wpf, shutdown

Here's a snippet of code where I pop up a simple dialog ("chooser").  Depending on the user's input, the application might terminate.

```
    DPChooser chooser = new DPChooser(dataProvider);
    if (chooser.ShowDialog() == false)
        Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
    else
        ApplicationContext.Current.InitializeDataProviderAPI(chooser.DataProvider);
    }

    // more code continues here
    // THE PROBLEM:
    //     Even when Shutdown() above is called,
    //     the execution continues proceeding past here!
```

I've run it in a debugger, so I **know** that the *if* is evaluating to false, and I **know** that Shutdown() is being called.

So why doesn't it shut down?

Note: it's not a threading thing, I think.  I'm not yet starting anything on other threads.  Even if threading was involved, I'd still not expect the code in this thread to keep proceeding past Shutdown().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shutdown stops the Dispatcher processing, and closes the application as far as WPF is concerned, but doesn't actually kill the current thread.

In your case, you need to prevent code beyond that call from running.   A simple return will suffice:

```
 if (chooser.ShowDialog() == false)
 {
     Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
     return;
 }
 else { //...
```

Comment: Heh, that's not so intuitive.  I should have thought to just put a return there, though, duh on me.  Thanks.

Comment: Wait, the docs for Shutdown(int exitCode) say that exitCode is returned to the operating system.  If the this method doesn't actually kill the app, how can the app use it to return this exitCode?

Comment: @GrantB It's a controlled shutdown, which doesn't stop the executing thread.  If you're using the default WPF plumbing, then this exit code is what gets returned from the entry point, but it happens after everything else executes (as you've discovered here).

Comment: by storing it in an application context most likely.....  good time to download dotPeek and have a look at how they implement it :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas It's actually the return value of Application.Run - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597010.aspx  The default plumbing returns this from the entry point routine.  It's never "stored" in the context.

Comment: The MSDN docs are a bit misleading - you don't HAVE to return that exit code to the process if you do your own application initailization, so the exit code return could be ignored.  It's really how the default plumbing handles it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't Terminate your process instantly,  its a controlled shutdown.

if you want ( not recommended ) to kill instantly

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

Comment: Environment.Exit() also works, but I knew it was equally not desirable.